# Passing std::string to C++ DLL for use with C# dll

Tags: c++, dll

I am trying to pass strings from a C++ console app to a C++ dll, which i then convert to System::string to be sent to a C# dll. But the string comes through as random characters. Note that lShutdown actually comes through correct as it is defined in the dll so the problem must be between the testapp and the C++ dll. I had this working before, but i cant figure out for the life of me how i did it

Here is the code for passing to the dll:

```
void GMSTestAppC::GMSSetup()
{
    string processName = "GMSCTestApp";
    string progName = "TestApp";
    //Directory where program is installed
    string progDir = "C:/";
    string version = "4.0.0.1";
    //Directory for config file
    string configDir = "C:/";
    //Directory for log files
    string logDir = "C:/";
    string user = "Smurf";
    string shutdownby = "";
    Initialize(processName, GetCurrentProcessId(), progName, progDir, version, configDir, logDir, user, shutdownby);
}
```

Here is the dll code:

```
bool Initialize(std::string& processName, int processID, std::string& programName, std::string& programDir, std::string& version, std::string& configDir, std::string& logDir, std::string& currentUser, std::string& lastShutDownBy)
    {
        String^ pName = gcnew String(processName.c_str());
        String^ progName = gcnew String(programName.c_str());
        String^ progDir = gcnew String(programDir.c_str());
        String^ cDir = gcnew String(configDir.c_str());
        String^ lDir = gcnew String(logDir.c_str());
        String^ cUser = gcnew String(currentUser.c_str());
        String^ lShutdown = gcnew String("test");
        GMS::GMSVersion fv;
        sscanf_s(version.c_str(), "%d.%d.%d.%d", &fv.Major, &fv.Minor, &fv.Revision, &fv.Build);
        int pID = int(processID);

        Return GMS::Initialize(pName, pID, progName, progDir, fv, cDir, lDir, cUser, lShutdown);
    }
```

Here is what i actually get through:

```
Sent: <InitializeProgram>
      <TimeStamp>2018-01-22T14:34:37.6152709+00:00</TimeStamp>
      <PID>13504</PID>
      <ProcessName>(÷'</ProcessName>
      <ProgramName>Ðð'</ProgramName>
      <ProgramDir>°ñ'</ProgramDir>
      <Version>0.0.0.0</Version>
      <ConfigDir>^ô'</ConfigDir>
      <LogDir>èñ'</LogDir>
      <CurrentUser>÷'</CurrentUser>
      <LastShutDownBy>test</LastShutDownBy>
    </InitializeProgram>
```

The characters that come through are different each time the program is run

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Looks like UTF-8 interpreted as ASCII (non-utf8 table). Try `std::wstring` instead of `std::string`.

Comment: @i486 Changing to wstring it now comes through as:

`Sent: <InitializeProgram>
  <TimeStamp>2018-01-22T15:07:12.9523702+00:00</TimeStamp>
  <PID>10804</PID>
  <ProcessName>?»</ProcessName>
  <ProgramName>?cTestApp</ProgramName>
  <ProgramDir>?cC:/</ProgramDir>
  <Version>0.0.0.0</Version>
  <ConfigDir>?cC:/</ConfigDir>
  <LogDir>?cC:/</LogDir>
  <CurrentUser>?cSmurf</CurrentUser>
  <LastShutDownBy>test</LastShutDownBy>
</InitializeProgram>`

The random 2 characters are different each time that i run it

Comment: Do you have `[DllImport]` for `Initialize` in C#? If yes - post its definition.

Comment: @i486

I have DllExport:

`[DllExport("Initialize", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.Cdecl)]`

Comment: @i486 have tried stdcall aswell, same result

Comment: `String^ pName` -- That is not C++.  Second, you better make sure your app and your DLL are built with the same compiler and compiler options.  If not, your `std::string` types will be different, and you can't mix / match differing string implementations.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie No that is a System::String, im converting to that to be passed to a c# dll.

Ill look through my compiler options now

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++11 (which you most probably be using), you can try using `std::u32string`. It removes the need to use `std::wstring` and is standard across platforms.